# Dashing Meter read file Json and send value

Tags: ruby, json, dashing

I need to send a value to dashing meter from a json file :
Parse dont work too contents = JSON.parse(file.read)

```
require 'json'


file = File.open('/mnt/json/process1.json')
contents = file.read

SCHEDULER.every '2s' do


  contents["poolused"] = { label: "poolused" , value: (contents["poolused"][:value])}
  send_event('synergy3',   { items: contents.values})

end
```

This is my json file

```
{   
    "label":"value",
    "PoolName":  "SDS2_D2600-SAS-450G-15K",
    "poolpercent":  "70",
    "Date":  "07/23/2015 15:33:57",
    "pooltotal":  "3540529446912",
    "poolused":  "2466384969728"
}
```

Error:

```
scheduler caught exception:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/home/toto/dashboard_v2/jobs/sample.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export file json with powershell : "ASCII" not UTF 16

```
 | ConvertTo-Json | Out-file d:\products\Dashing\json\process2.json -encoding ASCII
```

Send value to dashing

```
require 'json'


file = File.read('./process3.json')
counts = JSON.parse(file)

SCHEDULER.every '2s' do

  synergy14 = counts["poolused"]

  send_event('synergy3',   { value: synergy14} ) 

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `contents` variable contains JSON string read from file.
To transform it into hash you'll need
`contents = JSON.parse(file.read)`

Comment: Error /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at '▒▒{' (JSON::ParserError)

Comment: As you can see from the error message, when you read JSON string from file there's something prepending you JSON `'▒▒{'`. If you can somehow share that JSON file I'll be able to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Glupo, but i cant share file, all was bloqued by my business, file like on the top process1.json

Comment: Here's how it works on my side: http://pastebin.com/BkUixYeR
Copied the above json content to the file. What you'd probably have to do is to validate what you have inside of the file and gsub unwanted characters.

Comment: I put "-encoding ASCII" at my powershell script. and its run. because its was in UTF -16 and not work. " | ConvertTo-Json | Out-file d:\process2.json -encoding ASCII "

Answer (score 1):

```
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: unexpected token at '▒▒{' (JSON::ParserError)
```

Error with :

```
file = File.open('/mnt/json/process1.json') 
contents = JSON.parse(file.read)
```